# How to move around the gradient spline

Tags: node-editor

I want to animate a gradient node moving around from left to right, but I cannot figure out how to. I tried the Color Ramp and the Mapping node to control the gradient spline.

This is the node setup I have at this point
[image: Node setup gradient]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can key-frame the location field(s) in the Mapping node.

At the moment you are mapping in Camera space, (i.e. the space of the whole rendered screen in XY, and Z in and out of it.) Maybe one of the spaces associated with your object would suit your purposes better, it depends what you want to do.

Select 'Texture' in the Mapping node, and right-click in any of the  Location fields to set keyframes, and  animate the position of the texture in X/Y/Z.

Frame 5:

[image: Frame 5]

Frame 40:

[image: Frame 40]

Answer (score 2):

Just add the sine of time to it, the time can be computed using Animation Nodes and passed to Cycles as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Personally, I think the description of this (perfectly good) solution needs fleshing out. There's no guarantee the OP or less experienced readers will know anything about Animation Nodes, or even that you are using them?

Comment: @RobinBetts You are right. I will add another method using drivers.

Comment: It seems I don't know how to use drivers. I will let a more experienced user add a driver approach in another answer.

Comment: I thought your AN approach was fine - I just thought you could make it clear you were using them. (not everyone knows what they are, or what they look like.)  If @jspr comes back wanting automation, we can cross that bridge when we get there :)